# How would I rewrite this JavaScript loop in Ruby?

Tags: javascript, ruby

Code:

```
var some_var = [/*.......*/];
var compare_var;
for (var i = 0; i < some_var.length - 1; i++){
    if (some_var[i] <= compare_var && compare_var < some_var[i + 1]){
        return some_var[i];
    }
}
```

One value of `some_var` is 30 and the next one is 40 and the next one is 50 and `compare_var` is 42.

It wouldn't return 30 even though it's less-than 42, because 42 isn't less-than 40. Which also means that it would return 40 because it's less-than 42 and 42 is less-than 50.

**Edit:**

As someone mentioned code translation is not exactly great for SE.so. Just to make it clear: I did try several different things in ruby. I have way more experience in javascript though, so the best way I could think of to phrase my question was to write what I needed out in javascript so that I could see how it translated into ruby. Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a one-liner:

```
some_var.select{|v| v < compare_var}.max
```

Comment: +1 very cool, although if the lower bound number appears early in the array then the "select" method will still compare all of the elements instead of returning immediately (which really only matters for very large arrays).

Comment: True. My philosophy is develop for readability, then performance if necessary. If it was a very large array, I'd do it differently. But note that this solution handles an unsorted array :-P

Comment: Thanks, the array is not large so this worked like a charm! +1

Answer (score 3):

I would use the neato [`Enumerable#each_cons(n)` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons):

```ruby
def foo(arr, x)
  arr.each_cons(2) do |a,b|
    return a if (a <= x) && (x < b)
  end
  nil # Not found
end

foo([30,40,50], 42) # => 40
```

This basically creates a "sliding window" of each pair and then you can just return the first item of the pair when you find the pair that encloses the target value (x).

Comment: FYI: `lower_bound([30,50,40], 42) # => 30`

Comment: @MarkThomas: ah, perhaps I misunderstood the meaning of upper/lower bounds.  I've changed the function name to something less presumptuous =)

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of `var` key word, change `for` loop into `some_var.each`, and you get a working code in Ruby.

PS. Code translation is not proper in StackOverflow

Comment: It's OK if they first attempt a solution, and then ask specific questions about it.

Comment: @MarkThomas Well the poster just wanted a translated code, rather than an optimized one.

Comment: I def tried things out first but couldn't quite figure it out in ruby. I know javascript much better and could picture how the code should look there so I re-wrote what I had done in ruby in javascript then made it work.